# Как определить синтаксическую роль слова в SpaCy?

Tags: python, spacy

Пробовал использовать этот скрипт:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("ru_core_news_sm")
doc = nlp("Вегетарианцы городка в Калифорнии устроили митинг")
sent = next(doc.sents)
deps = [_.dep_ for _ in sent if _.i != _.head.i and _.dep_ not in ["punct"]]

print(deps)
```

Код выдаёт такой маасив:
`['nsubj', 'nmod', 'case', 'nmod', 'obj']`.
Расшифровку этих "синтаксических ролей" я нигде не смог найти.

Как расшифровываются эти значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще легко гуглится по именно этим словам. Вот, например, [даже с примерами](http://fginter.github.io/docs/ru/dep/all.html).
Там, правда, объяснения на английском, но примеры на русском в основном.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ещё ссылка.](https://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/)

Comment: На этом сайте все роли, которые есть в spaCy?

Comment: @LeeM Ну там много вообще-то на сайте и это штуки универсальные, они из предметной области, библиотека `SpaCy` просто с этой предметной областью работает.